# Files copied to USB disappeared without updating free space count

Tags: usb

This is a really weird issue that I've never encountered before and I can't find anything about online.

Basically, I was doing some basic tech support for someone which involved backing up files, reinstalling the OS, and restoring the files. The OS was busted so I directly removed the hard drive and copied the User folder to my PC (running Linux). The folder weighed about 24 GB in total. Once I did everything I decided to copy the files onto a USB stick formatted as exFAT, then copying them to the computer in question. There were no issues with the process at all.

However, immediately after plugging the drive in the PC (running Windows 10), the folder suddenly dropped to only about 9 GB! I connected it back to my main desktop and, indeed, the directory size decreased. I verified this through multiple methods (including du -sh and ls -something). I force deleted it and I only gained back the 9 GB that were displayed, the rest kept taking up storage space even though the folder was gone.

I tried copying again, and verified multiple times to make sure the file size was correct. It was. However, again, the size dropped to 9 GB immediately after connecting it to that specific computer. And after doing a hard delete I now have a 64 GB USB flash drive that reports 11 GB free, yet only has 11 GB of real used space.

Lastly, I said screw it and disconnected the hard drive (obviously formatted as NTFS) and just transferred all the files to it. I verified again, the directory was indeed 24 GB. But after booting the OS it, again, dropped to 9 GB. So it's not a drive issue. The only things I noticed was that the only folders affected were the AppData, and a Backup folder on the desktop (which appeared to be a backup of the User folder as well).

I could probably get away with formatting my USB and just copying files back to it, but a way to clean the "ghost" data would probably be more convenient and useful to know in the future. But what I'm really interested in is the reason for this, how is this actually possible? It's clearly not a random occurrence since the files were affected in the same exact way three times. And it doesn't seem to either be a file system or drive problem, nor has it ever occurred to me while using Windows 10.

For the record, before anyone asks, I always safely unmount my drives before disconnecting them. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run `chkdsk`? Usually that will find and (attempt to) recover orphaned files. As for the cause... that's harder to guess given it happens on both exFAT and NTFS. How was the OS "busted" and how did you reinstall it?

Comment: 'chkdsk' finds corruptions, but doing trying to fix them doesn't seem to do anything. It still detects the wrong free/used space capacity. I also tried fsck and exfatfsck and it doesn't work either. Basically the OS wouldn't boot and tried to repair the drive or something, so I formatted the partition and simply installed it through the DVD like normal. I can't say for sure whether the hard drive has problems, but even if it did, it doesn't seem that something that should happen.

Comment: Yea, this entire situation sounds bizarre. I assume you tried the `/F` flag on `chkdsk`? If you add `/V` does it list the missing files?

Comment: Correct, I did /f. /v doesn't work because it's not FAT32. I've tried a couple of other commands, and interestingly, I gained back about 20 GB, but nothing more. I actually managed to completely solve the problem without formatting - turns out Windows has a disk cleanup option and it detected an extra 14.4 GB worth of "old chkdsk files". After deleting them (numerous times, since it only deleted a few gigs at a time), I eventually got all my space back, which is nice. That being said, I'm still really stumped as to how this all happened or how it could have happened.